# Routing based on permissions in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to route the path based on the permissions a particular user has. I am using `react-router-dom`.

Here is my sample code:

```
 <Switch>

    <CustomRoute path="/add-user" name="Add user" component={AddUser} authorize='Can_Add_User' />
    <CustomRoute path="/del-user" name="Delete user" component={DelUser} authorize='Can_Del_User' />
    <CustomRoute path="/edit-user" name="Edit user" component={EditUser} authorize='Can_Edit_User' />
    <CustomRoute path="/list-user" name="List user" component={ListUser} authorize='Can_List_User' />

 </Switch>
```

I made my `CustomRoute` class where I passed additional `authorize` custom prop to it. Inside `CustomRoute` I compare the `authorize` prop with list of available permissions and if success return `Route` else return `null`.

Here is `CustomRoute.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';


// get permissions sets of current user from server
const permissions_set = //load from server.

class CustomRoute extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    hasPermission() {
        const authorize = this.props.authorize;

        if (permissions_set.includes(authorize)) {
            console.log('Permission exists');
            return true
        }

        return false;
    }

    render() {
        const { name, component, path, exact } = this.props;

        if (this.hasPermission()) 
            return  <Route path={path} name={name} component={component} />
        else return null;

    }
}

export default CustomRoute;
```

Now when the permission successfully matches, it displays correctly returning the `Route`. But when it does not has the permission and returns 
null, the `URL` still works but does not display any data. Should not the URL also not work. How to make it such that the URL too does not exists ?

**Note:** One method would be to redirect to another /not-found url in the `else case` but is it the nice way to do or are there other methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Protected routes and authentication with React Router v4. [Click here to ref](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1. Click the public page
// 2. Click the protected page
// 3. Log in
// 4. Click the back button, note the URL each time

const AuthExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <AuthButton />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

const AuthButton = withRouter(
  ({ history }) =>
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <p>
        Welcome!{" "}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
          }}
        >
          Sign out
        </button>
      </p>
    ) : (
      <p>You are not logged in.</p>
    )
);

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const Public = () => <h3>Public</h3>;
const Protected = () => <h3>Protected</h3>;

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false
  };

  login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return <Redirect to={from} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Log in</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

it should definitely redirect to something else

```
<Redirect to={{
  pathname: pathname,
  state: { from: props.location }
}/>
```

look at this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) on react-router  .